# Why does my website show lag in Chrome when I scroll?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-chrome

I'm facing this problem only in chrome. When I scroll up and down, I'm facing lag. This only happens in Chrome browser and I have the latest version. Website is based on PHP framework. Could anyone please identify the problem? Is there a problem with the website or the browser? Here is the website link: http://airfuz.com
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple PHP code is being used here. Nothing fancy. The articles are being loaded from a MySQL database.

Comment: Do you have any javascript/jquery listeners for page scroll/any movement?

Comment: No, no javascript/jquery listeners are being used for page scrolling or any sort of movement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that one cause is the massive image in the center. (the guy with the google glass) - this image is more than 5000px X 3400px+ but scaled down to around 500px. Which is together with other large images on the page. http://airfuz.com/Images/2014/05/man-wearing-google-glass.jpg

when i remove that image, it scrolls much smoother...

Consider using a php thumbnailing script (like [timthumb](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) or [phpthumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)) to actually serve images close to the size they will be shown. This will also benefit the load times of the site.

Comment: Are you facing lag in Chrome too? And can you please tell me whether you're facing any lag in other browsers? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes i saw some 'juttering' when scrolling if that's what you mean. The problem was apparent in firefox, but really only when it was loading.

Answer (score 1):

Your website has too large assets that simultaneously loads. Maybe that is the cause of the problem. Here's why I've concluded with this answer:

- When the website's assets are loading, the scrolling lags. (Tested with Chrome & Firefox)
- After the website has fully loaded, my Google Chrome shows less lag. While on the other hand, Firefox showed me no difference at all.

You could shrink down some assets, I think that will, somehow, lessen the lag.

---

And I noticed something about your website, you are using the HTML5 Doctype. However you are also using HTML4 Mark-up Tags (I saw the `<center>` tag). Well, this might not affect the problem but this will affect HTML5 Validity. =)

Well, hope I helped somehow.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Yes, since I have so much content on the home page, there's just too many images. Checking the previous answer, I guess the only way to stop the lagging is by shrinking down the images. Thank you again for your suggestion. Let me know if there's any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome [notorious bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753053#c3) Issue 753053